# What Does this // mean in PYTHON

Tags: python

What Does this // mean in PYTHON

I know it is some sort of division in python 
like 

 6.0//5  is 1.0

6.0//4  is 1.0

6.0//2  is 3.0

6.8//5.3 is 1

from this I think it just returns integer solution for non integer division 
and instead of rounding it just cut's end off is it true ? and if it is not
then what it does ? rounding 


 I found answer sorry i will delete this post :)

Answer (score 0):

Floor Divison. I.e. round down to nearest int.